# The plugin generated 683 characters of unexpected output during activation

Tags: plugin-development

i am facing this error, please help me.

```
<?php
 /*Plugin Name: Contact Form
 Plugin URI: http://localhost/redspark/wp-admin
 Description: Contact Form Create & Retrive By Ajax
 Author: Shifa Memon
 Author URI: http://localhost/redspark/wp-admin
 Version: 1.0 */
 function custom_contact_form_create(){
// echo "Active";
// die();
global $wpdb;
global $table_prefix;
$table = $table_prefix . 'contact_us';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE 'wp_contact_us' (
      `id` int(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `subject` text NOT NULL,
      `message` longtext NOT NULL,
      `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON 
       UPDATE current_timestamp())";
       $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'custom_contact_form_create');

function custom_contact_form_delete(){
   global $wpdb;
   global $table_prefix;
   $table = $table_prefix.'contact-us';
   $sql = "DROP TABLE $table";
   $wpdb->query($sql);
   // echo "Deactivate";
  }
  register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__ ,'custom_contact_form_delete');

    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: you should use the wpdb prefix variable instead of hardcoding `wp_` to avoid conflicts and support multisite, and `dbDelta` to create the table. Also us the triple back tick syntax for code highlighting instead of indenting, it will be easieer

Comment: i try with dbDelta but error is occur

Comment: `dbDelta` is very particular about how it's used and the formatting of the code. You also need to include a particular file before using it. Is the code in your question the entire plugin?

Comment: yes you are right, but i didn't use `dbDelta` , without using this i fixed it..error was in formatting. you can see at below i posted answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally plugin is activated...

[image]

this is code...

[image]

Comment: What was the fix? It looks like you just removed the close tag `?>` ?

Comment: I have placed a screenshot so the php close tag does not appear.. it was a little mistake u see code properly..